# Copying folders to another destination, naming destination folders based on original creation date

Tags: powershell

I need to copy content from the source folder with sub folders that contain sub folders and files. This needs to be copied to a destination folder based on the date of the source by year and month so I would like a folder called 2013 then a month 1 and then the source folder contents.

I have looked through Microsoft documentation but cannot yet find what I need to do to produce what I want.

Code source courtesy of https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2015/03/move-files-to-folder-sorted-by-year-and-month-with-powershell/

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test1' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}
$files
$targetPath = 'D:\Test2'
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
    $month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString()
    $file.Name
    $year
    $month
    $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $year + "\" + $month
    if (!(Test-Path $Directory)) {
        New-Item $directory -Type Directory
    }
    $file | Copy-Item -Recurse -Destination $Directory 
}
```

This code does most of what I want but does not re-create the sub folders, it only copies the files into the newly created year and month folders.

Comment: use `copy-item -recurse` for doing the copy recursively

Comment: I added that in but it made no difference

Comment: Wiley: Edit you question and post where you made the change.

Comment: I changed the last line of code from this $file | Copy-Item -Destination $Directory 
} to this   $file | Copy-Item -Recurse -Destination $Directory 
}

Comment: You're enumerating all *files* in your source folder. What you need to do is enumerate the subfolders of your source folder, and then recursively copy their content. `Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test1' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}` -> `Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test1\*' | where {$_.PsIsContainer}`

Comment: The `->` in @AnsgarWiechers comment means that you need to **REPLACE** the code `Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test1' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}` with `Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test1\*' | where {$_.PsIsContainer}`, not copy the whole thing including the `->`

Comment: Thank you so much that works a treat.

Comment: Please do not edit the solution into your question, since that would make your question pointless.